# Custom function substring Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, substring, custom-function

I'm trying to integrate a substring method in a custom function, but I'm getting a error.  My function is something simple like :

```
Var num = "1234567"
Var num2 = Num.slice(0,2)
```

I can't make it run inside a custom function that I want to use as a formula.

Comment: Custom functions have some restrictions.

Comment: Can you provide the whole script for replicating your issue? And about `I can't make it run inside a custom function that I want to use as a formula.`, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script /JavasScript are case sensitive.

1. Use `var` instead of `Var`
2. Your code declares a variable as `num` no `Num`.